# Printing a "Printable" object to a PDF file silently

Tags: java, pdf, printing

How can I print a "java.awt.print.Printable" object silently to a PDF?
Few things to note:

- I do not have the data as a pdf file
- I'm working on existing code, so I cannot step away from the printable interface

So i can print it just fine with job.printDialog(). But I need to be able to do that silently (without user input). The available PDF printer is "Adobe PDF", I suppose others can be installed if needed.

Here's the basic code:

```
Printable printout = /*object*/;
Book pageable = new Book();
pageable.append(printout, pageFormat);

DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE;
PrintRequestAttributeSet patts = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

// Add Filepath?

PrintService[] ps = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, patts);
if (ps.length == 0)
    throw new IllegalStateException("No Printer found");

PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.setPrintService(ps[0]);

job.setPrintable(printout);
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually decided to step away from trying to do it in java and instead used a PDF printer which has the option to print silently to a predetermined path.

```
DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE;
PrintRequestAttributeSet patts = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
PrintService[] ps = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, patts);

System.out.println("Available printers: " + Arrays.asList(ps));

PrintService myService = null;
for (PrintService printService : ps) {
    if (printService.getName().contains("PDF Writer - bioPDF")) {
        myService = printService;
        break;
    }
}

if (myService == null) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("bioPDF Printer not found");
}

PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.setJobName(jobName);
job.setPrintService(myService);
job.setPrintable(printout);

job.print();
```